# Using Pusher/Pubnub with an authoritative game server

Tags: html, websocket, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I'd like to build a 2-player turn based game with an authoritative server to manage the game state/logic. The flow I have in mind is something like:

- Players are subscribed to a unique game channel (via pubnub/pusher/something similar)
- Players submit their turns over HTTP directly to the game server
- The server runs the game logic and publishes the result to the game's channel (which both players are subscribed to)
- The client handles the response and renders the outcome
- matchmaking kind of confuses me though. Any suggestions?

Is that the "right" way of using a pub/sub service in this scenraio? Is there a better approach (something other than polling the server constantly)?

Answer (score 2):

This is a heated topic at our office!  I've been using PubNub as an authoritative game server using creative choice of channel names.  It works like this:

1. Run a node.js server (doesn't have to be node; can be anything) that serves your content, and also acts as an authoritative entity.
2. When a client connects, generate a UUID (can be done either server-side or client-side) and have both the client and server listen on that channel (something like "my_game_[UUID]").
3. Because no other clients know this channel name, the client and server can communicate freely on this channel.
4. The server can talk to everyone, and clients can perform secure actions through the server and communicate with each other using an "unsecure" vanilla pubnub channel.

Comment: That's pretty much what I had in mind. However, sending data from the client to the server doesn't technically need to be over pubnub. It can be a simple http request.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal sounds great and is the "right" way.  The challenge you face is shared from the beginning of the computer epoch, where synchronizing data is a requirement between multiple devices such as a mobile smartphone.  Polling is SLOW and expensive (and does not make sense for a large number of players).  Multiplayer games is a great example need to pair players and provide game rooms.  Your solution is to:

1. Create a Game Lobby, where players can create game rooms and join game rooms.
2. Create an Auto-Pair of players (Quick Join) [Recommended]

You may solve this technical challenge with products such as Socket.IO and some other open source options.  However you want to just build your game rather than focus on deploying a Node.JS server and hooking it up to Express.

Instead use a Cloud Service like [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/), PusherApp or Beacon Push.  Utilize the Pub/Sub API to synchronize users in a multiplayer environment easily.